# Neo4J Depth if there a node between 2 nodes

Tags: neo4j

I have the following query:

```
MATCH
   (exp:Expert {name: "Somebody"})-[:PUBLISHED_BY]-(pub1:Publication)-[:PUBLISHED_BY]-(coexp:Expert),
   (coexp:Expert)-[:PUBLISHED_BY]-(pub2:Publication)-[:PUBLISHED_BY]-(cocoexp:Expert)
RETURN exp,pub1,pub2,coexp,cocoexp
LIMIT 300
```

What I'd like to return is the following:

```
(expert)--(publication)--(coexpert)
(expert)--(publication)--(coexpert)--(publication)--(cocoexpert)
```

But it returns also:

```
(expert)--(publication)--(coexpert)--(publication)--(cocoexpert)--(publication)--(cococoexpert)
...
```

In the second part I tried to do:

```
(coexp:Expert)-[:PUBLISHED_BY]-(pub2:Publication)-[:PUBLISHED_BY*0..1]-(cocoexp:Expert)
```

But no success. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query has cardinality issue. If you want to match the second part optionally you can separate it and add an optional match clause to it.
Following query should work as expected:

```
MATCH (exp:Expert {name: "Somebody"})-[:PUBLISHED_BY]-(pub1:Publication)-[:PUBLISHED_BY]-(coexp:Expert)
OPTIONAL MATCH (coexp)-[:PUBLISHED_BY]-(pub2:Publication)-[:PUBLISHED_BY]-(cocoexp:Expert)
Where exp<>coexp And exp<>cocoexp And coexp<>cocoexp
RETURN exp,pub1,pub2,coexp,cocoexp
LIMIT 300
```

Comment: This query returns the coco-experts, so it works. But is it possible to do that with only one query (co-experts and coco-experts)? Is the zero length paths could help? Thanks.

Comment: This query returns both co-experts and coco-experts. Are you facing any issues?

Comment: If I execute this query I will retrieve only a co-expert if there is a coco-expert. I'd like to  retrieve a co-expert even if there is no coco-expert. If experts were linked together directly without a publication, I know how to do that. But I don't know how to do with a node (Publication) between experts.

Comment: Edited the query, Can you verify it?

Comment: It works! Thanks. If co-expert is 1st degree, coco-expert 2nd degree... is there a generic way (without writing all the relationships,nodes) to say I want to return all experts between the 2nd and 4th degrees for example? Still with a publication between 2 experts.

Comment: I don't think if there is a generic way for this. You may consider adding extra relationship(like CO_EXPERTS) which will connect experts. Then it will be possible

Comment: Thanks Raj! A direct connection would be indeed easier.